# How to change static text in a web page using inner html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text in a website that I want to change using javascript because I can't change it any other way.

In short, the site is laid out like such:

```
...some other divs before here, body, head, etc...
<div id="header" class="container-fluid clearfix">
    <div class = "hero-unit">
        <h1 class="title">Support Center</h1>
...some other divs for other parts of the page...
    </div>
</div>
...more divs, footer, etc...
```

I don't need the text to change on click or anything like that I just want it to be set on load to something different than `Support Center` but I'm not sure if I'm placing the script in the correct place or if the syntax is wrong?

I've tried placing it before and after and it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var targetDiv = document.getElementByID("header").getElementsByClassName("hero-unit")[0].getElementsByClassName("title")[0];
targetDiv.innerHTML = "Please use the Knowledge Base to find answers to the most frequently asked questions or you may submit a support ticket which will be sent to your COM email account.";
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: In Javascript case matters, its: `getElementById` notice the lower case **d** on the end, you should be getting **undefined is not a function** in the javascript console (or similar error depending on browser)

Comment: Damn... well, I fixed that and then tried it again, still no changes to the text. I tried having the script before and after the relevant divs, and nothing. Should this script go before or after these divs in my HTML file? In the console, if I put the script after, the error I get now is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined default.asp?deptID=15028:142(anonymous function)", if I put it before, I get "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null".

Comment: Are you sure you didn't break anything while fixing what @PatrickEvans noticed? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fseza1ff/ - it works as expected after this small correction.

Comment: Yes I'm positive, let me double check. and yeah I just ran it in JSFiddle too and noticed it does work. Edit: double checked my code, it's exactly as I have it in my working fiddle.

Comment: Are there other elements on the page with an id of `header`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, the page in question is http://s5-sandbox.parature.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=15028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the actual source of your page, your page does not contain a `h1` element with a class of `title`.

> Your actual source code
>
> ```
> <div id="header" class="container-fluid clearfix">
>
>     <div class="hero-unit"></div> 
>     <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
>          <div class="row-fluid">
>              <div class="leftcolumn"></div>
>              <div class="rightcolumn"></div>
>          </div> 
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

This means it does not exist till some point after your page loads. You need to put your code after the code that generates the h1 title element

Comment: Yes, finally got it. And I actually had to change a class name too.  Even though I was putting it at the very, very end of my page, for some reason I had to put it right after the code that appends that h1, which is "$('.titledesc').appendTo('#header > div');". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery (if you can use it), you'd use something like

```
$("#title").text("Something else");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this works just as well. $('#header .container-fluid.clearfix .title').text("Something else"); works great.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are not getting the specific class to change the html

try with `querySelector` like i have done

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2zctc2g/1/)

```
var targetDiv = document.querySelector('#header > .hero-unit > h1.title')
targetDiv.innerHTML = "Please use the Knowledge Base to find answers to the most frequently asked questions or you may submit a support ticket which will be sent to your COM email account.";
```